# Adding leading 0 to DateType

Tags: php, symfony

I created a Symfony form with DateType. In date field in value I had 1-31, when for 1-9 I need to add leading 0. Is there any way to do that using just Symfony tools/features?

```
$builder
    ->add('date_start', DateType::class, [
        'format' => 'ddMMyyyy',
        'years' => [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
    ])
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
;
```

Comment: The PHP itself has that functionality, it is called str_pad => https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php bo I have no idea how to put this into your code, maybe someone else will help :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch is correct, but Dawid wants a symfony based solution. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format. Date formats are still based on PHP date values https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php